# Unknown LED fixture replacement identification

Tags: light-fixture, led

After several months of trying (*without really trying*), I finally managed to remove my faulty ceiling LED fixture. I was expecting a standard LED bulb once the beast dismantled, alas not.

I am unable to identify the piece. The LED is encased in some sort of a radiator, and the connection looks like a circular plug used in some laptop charger (*with little stoppers to fix it in place*). I don't think the ceiling fixation should be included in the product, I just forgot to remove it before taking the photos.

**Any advice?**

Additional info: I live in France. The cable is chinese (*I read "52(RVV)" on it*), and I can barely read on the white plastic around the semiconductor; something like DEC2508-135135 or DEO2508-135135. Outer size (*diameter*) of the plug is 5mm. I can take more photos if needed.

[image: Semiconductor side]

[image: Plug side]

**Edit:** I don't think I can replace a smaller part than the whole piece. See third photo.

[image: LED detail]

**Edit 2:** following [Harper](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/221494/133548) answer, which I agree with, I forgot to say that I don't think the LED *per se* is at fault, because the light sometimes lights up when moving the whole when plugged-in. *But*, my question still stands; if I cannot repair it, how can I identify the whole device and where can I buy a replacement?

**Follow up:** I pulled the cable from the ceiling, I found a LED power supply (Model KEDH008S0200NR05, converting from 230 V to about 24 V) that emit a very faint alarm when the switch is on. It might be the source of the problem. I am no professional, and my landlord has no idea where to buy this.

[image: LED power supply]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barking up the wrong tree.

### The LED emitter is not defective

Since the beginning of artificial light, the emitting device has been a high-wear item that needs frequent replacement. We've been replacing logs, candles, wicks and bulbs for 10,000 years, so it seems perfectly reasonable that "surely the light emitting thing must be frequently replaced".

*You have charged headlong into this project with this assumption on your mind, and have never doubted it or re-examined it.*

In similar vein, vacuum tubes in radios once needed frequent replacement.  Now, they are replaced by semiconductor transistors that essentially never fail.

That is what has happened with LED.  The "light emitting thing" is a semiconductor, and is vanishingly unlikely to fail.   Not impossible, but on any light assembly, it's the least likely to fail.

**As such, LED light fixtures have no reason to make the 'bulb' replaceable**.

The electronic driver, which conditions supply power to the exact current flow needed for the LED, is a different matter.  It is full of less reliable parts such as capacitors and Chinese 'anything'.

What you certainly have there is a perfectly functional LED and a broken driver.

But don't take my word on it. Place that lamp onto a bench power supply.  Tell the power supply to supply 10 milliamps max (better power supplies let you do this - very important).  Then increase voltage until it lights.

Don't be tempted to run it at higher milliamps unless its heat sink is properly installed. That will burn it up.

### Look at the driver

I'm pretty sure France uses something like the Europlug, and not that tiny little barrel connector I see. Therefore, there is something between the little barrel socket and AC mains power.  My guess is the driver is an electrical "match" for that particular Cree emitter.  That, I think, is the item which has failed.

That driver module you photographed, the picture is too poorly lit and blurry to make out the figures, but it clearly says "Constant Current Type".  That's very important, and also not a surprise, since it is the nature of LEDs that they must be driven in a current-regulated fashion to get peak performance out of them.  (they are unable to self-limit their current the way an incandescent can).

Anyway, any driver should suffice so long as it has

- the exact current output that this driver states
- An input AC mains voltage range that is acceptable
- An output voltage range that is compatible with the LED emitter
- The necessary government certifications (CE is worthless, but note the "TUV" stamp just to the left of it).

Comment: As a physicist I am much inclined to agree with the fact that the cell is not at fault here, especially since (I forgot to add it in my question) the light seems to function when moving it while plugged-in. I didn't understand your last two sentences, do you think the failure is somewhere on the device in the picture, or somewhere between the ceiling cable plug and the main electrical system (not shown)?

Comment: Yes, @EPrivat,  looking at this unit and its proprietary plug (which is fit for DC and not mains)... I don't see any electronics.  There must be driver electronics; therefore they are between this thing and the AC mains source.  That is where I would look for the trouble. Any labeling on that unit would help to identify a replacement.

Comment: The remark on the DC current is a good (and obvious) one. I guess the fault resides in the LED power supply. Google and DuckDuckGo don't help me with the complete reference, but at least I'm closing in on the problem, thank you.

Comment: @EPrivat Yeah, it sounds like you need a driver.  I added some info to the end of my answer.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I couldn't manage to get a good picture but I can read all the specs. I'll validate your answer in a few days when I am positive about the fault and I can arrange with my landlord the most safe/legal way to fix it.

Comment: If you pop open the cover on that little driver box (while unplugged), you'll probably see brown staining where one of the components failed.  You'll want a better driver with a heatsinking metal enclosure if possible.  These little plastic drivers seem to have high failure rates.

Answer (score 0):

Remove those two Phillip screws and pull the plastic disk out of the fixture. Now you'll see the square led disk. It's number is Cree 1304N. You should be able to track it down and if you can solder, replace the square disk. You'll have to scrap off the old disk See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I don't think that'll work. See my edit.

Comment: @EPrivat  Yes, if the LED lights up sometime, then it's probably the driver and not the light. That would have been helpful info in your original post. :-)    I'll delete this answer if you confirm Harper's answer.

Comment: I don't think you should remove your answer in any case. While my problem is quite specific, and (possibly, not sure yet) resolved by changing the driver, you managed to find the exact LED reference. Which stays relevant I think.